# HTTPS with plaintext / HTTPS and Custom encryption functions?

Tags: javascript, security, web, encryption, https

**This question is more about web architecture than actual code behind it.**

I posted a question yesturday about how to fix a problem I was having about js encryption and decryption.
My whole system now works however I think I've just rebuilt https.

In my current app the client recieves a public key to encrypt data. That data is decrypted at the server with a private key which I've learnt is exactly the way https works. I was going to abandon my encryption functions completely however I thought that they might actually be useful.

This is because I thought I might have one server for handling requests and another for database interaction. So I would encrypt the plaintext password before it reached the request server (and then decrypt it after it reaches the database server). This is because the less places the password is known, the better (as far as I see it).

Not only that but I still don't feel safe sending a password as plaintext to the server even if it is encrypted.

There's probably a standard for sending passwords that I'm missing or something about https that I don't understand but really my question is:

*Should I have https and my encryption system?
or just https and sending the passwords in plaintext?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending the password as plaintext when you send it through HTTPs, but you should not store it on the server (or pass it to other server). What you should make to prevent the password to leak, is to salt and hash it and store the hash and salt on the database, you can read more about it on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)).

On the other hand, while building software from scratch is a good practice, it is important to review other implementations, so you can copy the implementation details on known open source secure implementations, like for example [devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/).